# Считать из файла и записать в лист с несколькими переменными-Tuple

Tags: c#

Нужно считать из текстового файла значения и записать их в лист, чтобы каждое значение записывалось в свою переменную. Например: `"1 января"`, `1` записывается в `int`, а `январь` в `string`

Вот данные:

```
1 января -5 Пасмурно
2 января -2 Облачно
3 января -4 Пасмурно
4 января -1 Дождь
5 января -2 Пасмурно
6 января -5 Пасмурно
7 января -11 Пасмурно
8 января -9 Снег
9 января -12 Пасмурно
10 января -11 Пасмурно
11 января -6 Снег
12 января -1 Пасмурно
13 января -2 Пасмурно
14 января -1 Пасмурно
15 января +1 Дождь
```

Умею это делать на `C` просто в различные переменные, а как сделать на `C#` тем более в лист, вообще не понимаю. Прошу помочь

```
List<Tuple<int, string, int, string>> lines = new List<Tuple<int, string, int, string>>();
FileStream file = new FileStream("weather.txt", FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(file);
            while (!readFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                lines.Add(new Tuple<int, string, int, string>(readFile.Read(), readFile.ReadLine(), readFile.Read(), readFile.ReadLine()));
            }
            readFile.Close();
```

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Файл то открыть на чтение получилось хотя бы?

Comment: @srvr4vr Да, все могу открыть, он и записывает в лист, но криво, не соблюдая пробелов, поэтому в переменную int попадают строки, а не в string

Comment: ну так вываливайте код) будем разбираться

Comment: @srvr4vr Код добавил в вопросе

Comment: я бы месяцы и состояние тоже бы в числах хранил...а в прого через перечисления

Comment: Если вы после каждой записи поставите "Enter" (после 1 января -5 Пасмурно). Потом будите считывать каждую строку, парсить ее и с массива выбирать в `Tupple`, то все заработает

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте 2 класса:

**1 класс (сущность):**

```
public class WeatherInfo
{
    public WeatherInfo(DateTime date, int temperature, string weatherFeature)
    {
        Date = date;
        Temperature = temperature;
        WeatherFeature = weatherFeature ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(weatherFeature));
    }

    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public int Temperature { get; private set; }
    public string WeatherFeature { get; private set; }
}
```

**2 класс:** (Using сам вызывает Dispose объектов в скобках, поэтому Close вызывать не надо.)

```
public static class WeatherWorker
{
    public static List<WeatherInfo> ParseWeatherInfoFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        List<WeatherInfo> weatherInfos = new List<WeatherInfo>();

        try
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string[] words = reader.ReadLine().Split(' ');

                        if (words.Length != 4)
                        {
                            throw new OperationCanceledException("Нарушение структуры исходного файла");
                        }

                        weatherInfos.Add(new WeatherInfo(DateTime.Parse(words[0] + "." + words[1]), Int32.Parse(words[2]), words[3]));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            // TODO: Обработать другие исключения.
        }

        return weatherInfos;
    }
}
```

Используйте так:

```
        List<WeatherInfo> weatherInfos = WeatherWorker.ParseWeatherInfoFromFile("D:\\weather.txt");

        if (weatherInfos.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parsed lines:");
            weatherInfos.ForEach(wi => Console.WriteLine(
                "Day: " + wi.Date.Day + ", Month: " + wi.Date.Month + ", Temperature: " + wi.Temperature + ", Feature: " + wi.WeatherFeature));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Можно не в DateTime пихать, а как вы сказали, сделать 2 поля:
public int Day { get; private set; }
public string Month { get; private set; }